# In ACR 8.6, is there a shortcut-key to toggle the "Convert to grayscale" checkbox?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-camera-raw, keyboard-shortcuts

In the "HSL / Grayscale" dialogue-box of Adobe Camera Raw (8.6) (part of Photoshop CS6),  is there a shortcut-key to toggle the "Convert to grayscale" checkbox?

[image: ACR HSL/Grayscale-dialogue screen-shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Macs, <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> works.

For PC, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: But any idea about on Windows? I'm guessing ctrl-alt-shift-G?

Comment: @mattdm Yup. Ctrl-Alt-Shift-G. Updating my answer now.

Comment: @dexterlo: Works for me. (I should have said I'm a Mac user.) Your help is much appreciated.